# C# Datetimepicker -Date search is not same as return result

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, datetimepicker

I have a problem with my stand alone C#.net application when comes to datetimepicker.
It tooks me weeks and not able to get it solve. I hope you can give me a hand.

I have a [create booking], [Search Booking], and [DB] using ms access.

1) Create booking date using the datetimepicker. 
format= short
`cmd.CommandText = "insert into booking(cname, bdate, btime, ccontact, sname) Values('" + txt_cname.Text + "','" + **dtp_bdate.Value.Date** + "','" + dtp_btime.Value + "','" + txt_ccontact.Text + "','" + txt_sname.Text + "')";`

2) Data store in DB is correct.
Example: 01/10/2011 (it is 1st of October 2011)

3) Search Booking date using the datetimepicker.
format= short

```
string strSql = String.Format("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE bdate = #{0}#", dtp_search.Value.Date);
```

When I try to search as in 01/10/2011. It doesn't return the result for me.
But when I try to search as in 10/1/2011, it then appeared the result.

I checked on the DB and confirm the date format is saved as 01/10/2011.
But I don't understand why and how this weird thing happen.

Can any kind man give me a hand?

Truly appreciated in advance.

Thank you,
Gary Yee

Comment: Just to confirm, but are you sure there isn't a "time" component associated with the date in the database?  Formatting will hide the real value.

Comment: The data type in the DB is date/time, format=short.
Also the date format display as dd/MM/yyyy.

So any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Access allows fixed format dates in sql queries (MM/DD/YYYY). And the date is displayed formatted according to the current culture of the database browser (so you get DD/MM/YYYY). Just use (MM/DD/YYYY) in queries.

Comment: The datetimepicker format show as dd/MM/yyy and when I trying to search 20/10/2011. It then return the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

"IF" your data is correct, try using parameters instead:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();

  using (var cn = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
  {
    cn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM booking WHERE bdate = @bdate", cn))
    {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bdate", dtp_bdate.Value.Date);
      using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
        oda.Fill(dt);
    }
  }
```

Otherwise, try debugging your statement by trying >= or <= for your "WHERE bdate = @bdate" statement to see if that changes the results.

Comment: I try your statement but compiled with one error.
"System.Data.OleDbDataReader" is a "type" but is used like a "Variable".

Comment: @GaryYee Fixed. Sorry, I was "var" happy.

Comment: Thanks but another error....
Cannot convert method group "ExecuteReader" to non delegate type....

Comment: @GaryYee Updated.  Keyboard not working today.  I also added the cn.Open();

Comment: I have a datagridview table, it is using to output the matched date.

How should I write the command and it should under the 'while (rdr.Read())'??

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Your coding works!! I added 'GridView1.DataSource = dt;' after the 'oda.Fill(dt);' and the result is show accordingly in dd/MM/yyyy format. Thanks again, sharing is wonderful in life :)